# Can i use a cursor after immediately creating a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**Here i firstly create the bonuses table when i call execute immediate create_table and fill_table and then the cursor i to fetch data from it,
but it gives me an error of table or view does not exist
**.

> ```
> declare
>
>    --My table
>    create_table VARCHAR2( 100 ) :=  '
>    create table bonuses
>   (
>     employee_id NUMBER(6), bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100
>   )';
>
> ---String query that fetch data from hr and oe tables to fill bonus table
>   fill_table VARCHAR2( 200 ) :=   'INSERT INTO bonuses(employee_id)
>    (SELECT employee_id FROM hr.employees e, oe.orders o
>    WHERE e.employee_id = o.sales_rep_id
>    GROUP BY e.employee_id)  ';
>
>   CURSOR foo is 
>   select A.employee_id, A.salary 
>   FROM HR.employees A
>   JOIN HR.DEPARTMENTS B
>   ON A.department_id = B.DEPARTMENT_ID
>   JOIN HR.LOCATIONS C
>   ON B.location_id = C.location_id
>   JOIN  HR.COUNTRIES D
>   ON C.COUNTRY_ID = D.COUNTRY_ID
>   JOIN HR.REGIONS E 
>   ON D.REGION_ID = E.REGION_ID
>   WHERE E.REGION_NAME = 'Europe';
>
> begin
>
> execute immediate create_table;
> execute immediate fill_table;
> commit;
>
> ---here happens the error
> FOR i IN ( SELECT employee_id FROM bonuses) LOOP
>
>     FOR j in foo LOOP
>
>       IF i.employee_id = j.employee_id THEN
>           dbms_output.put_line( 1 );
> --        UPDATE bonuses set bonus = bonus + j.salary * 0.01;
>       ELSE
>           dbms_output.put_line( 2 );
> --        UPDATE bonuses set bonus =  j.salary * 0.01;
>       END IF; 
>     END LOOP;
> END LOOP;
>
> end;
> ```
>
> [and this is the error that a get after executing. I am using a sys
>   session by the way.][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMtWV.png

Comment: Let's see it from the Oracle point of view: how can Oracle know that your string will create a table `bonuses`? Oracle knows that at the time you run the script this table does not exist, so you can not use it. If you need to create a table with dynamic sql ( and this is not a great idea if you don't striclty need it) you only can use it in dynamic sql.